# Multiple labels in html alignment

Tags: javascript, html, label

I have the following code to define four separate labels in html:

```
<label for="months" id="months" >Months</label>
<label for="weeks" id="weeks">Weeks</label>
<label for="fortnights" id="fortnights">Fortnights</label>
<label for="quarters" id="quarters">Quarters</label>
```

I have defined a java script function to hide these labels when the page loads.
I have a separate java script function to only show one label at a time depending on what has been selected in a different drop down.
This works as it should.

My issue in this scenario is that the labels do not display in the desired location on the page. They display in different places, is there a way to get these labels to display in the same place on the page and not in different places?

Cheers,
Mike

Hi Matt,
Here is my JavaScript function to hide the labels on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function hideLabels()
            {
                //alert("Entered hideLabels function");
                document.getElementById("months").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("weeks").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("fortnights").style.visibility = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("quarters").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        </script>
```

Here is my Javascript function to only display one label at a time depending on the value of another drop down field on the page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function FrequencyChange(value)
            {
                if (value == 1)
                {
                    document.getElementById("months").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("weeks").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("quarters").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("fortnights").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                if (value == 2)
                {
                    document.getElementById("weeks").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("months").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("quarters").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("fortnights").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                if (value == 3)
                {
                    document.getElementById("quarters").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("months").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("weeks").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("fortnights").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
                if (value == 4)
                {
                    document.getElementById("fortnights").style.visibility = "visible";
                    document.getElementById("months").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("weeks").style.visibility = "hidden";
                    document.getElementById("quarters").style.visibility = "hidden";
                }
            }
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Can you share your javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include it on the html too.

```html
<label for="months" id="months" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">Months</label>
<label for="weeks" id="weeks"style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">Weeks</label>
<label for="fortnights" id="fortnights"style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">Fortnights</label>
<label for="quarters" id="quarters" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;">Quarters</label>
```

Comment: Cheers Wilson, this was a great help. Although I didnt want to display the labels in the top left of the page I have been able to move them around changing the values for top and left: e.g.:

    <label for="months" id="months" style="position:absolute;top:110px;left:740px;">Months</label>

Answer (score 1):

You can use css:

```
    label{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, is there any way to do this without using css?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *visibility* property , you need to use *display* property for this purpose

**visibility** : when hidden , element is hidden from users but the element display area is still left as is

**display** : when none , element is removed from the DOM , thus the element display area is recovered

@Mike check my plunker for your usecase using display property

https://plnkr.co/edit/h0dDyZZbmZBbbqfg50Rm

```
function hideLabels() {
  //alert("Entered hideLabels function");
  document.getElementById("months").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("weeks").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("fortnights").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("quarters").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Raaghu. Your Plunder page is great and I can see how this works! 
Cheers,
Mike